# Изменить URI при помощи ModRewrite в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Помогите сделать так, чтобы при обращению по такому uri:
/dir1/abc
Сервер произвел запрос на:
/test/dir1/?id=abc
dir1 и abc могут быть любыми
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /test/%1/?id=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Потестил, работает, благодарю